# Bash - Uninstall Application with Dialog Box Confirmation

Tags: xcode, bash, macos, installation, applescript

I have an example of what I want the dialog to look like with Applescript but can't figure out how to do the same in a Bash file.

Bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
app="/Applications/Cisco Spark.app"
FileToDelete=$app
if [ -d "$app" ];  # Remove, if exists.
then
echo ""$FileToDelete""
rm -r "$FileToDelete" #Removing App 
else
echo $app
fi
```

Applescript:

```
display dialog "Webex Teams is replacing Cisco Spark! This installation will close and uninstall Cisco Spark." buttons {"Cancel Installation", "Install Teams"} default button "Install Teams"


if result = {button returned:"Install Teams"} then
    tell application "Cisco Spark"
        quit
    end tell
end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with. Works great! Thanks for the help!

```
#!/bin/bash
response=$(osascript -e 'button returned of (display dialog "Webex Teams is replacing Cisco Spark!\n" & "The full installation will close and uninstall Cisco Spark." buttons {"Cancel Spark Removal", "Remove Spark"} default button "Remove Spark")')

    # Exit script if user cancels
    [[ "$response" = "Cancel Spark Removal" ]] && exit 0

    #If not cancelled, delete application
    FileToDelete="/Applications/Cisco Spark.app"
    if [ -d "$FileToDelete" ];  # Remove, if exists.
    then
    echo "Closing Cisco Spark"
    killall "Cisco Spark" || echo "Spark wasn't open"
    echo "removing Cisco Spark.app"
    rm -r "$FileToDelete"
    else
    echo "Cisco Spark is not installed on this device"
    fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified version of your bash script, which includes the dialog popup allowing the user to cancel or continue, as in your AppleScript:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    response=$(osascript -e 'button returned of ¬
              (display dialog "Webex Teams is replacing Cisco Spark!\n" & ¬
              "This installation will close and uninstall Cisco Spark." ¬
              buttons {"Cancel Installation", "Install Teams"} ¬
              default button "Install Teams")')

    # Exit script if user cancels
    [[ "$response" = "Cancel Installation" ]] && exit 1

    # Get PID of "Cisco Spark" application
    pid=$(lsappinfo info -only pid "Cisco Spark" | egrep -o '\d+')
    # If running, quit the application
    [[ -z "$pid" ]] || kill -QUIT $pid

    # Delete the application file
    app="/Applications/Cisco Spark.app"
    rm -R "$app" 2>/dev/null && echo "Done." || echo "$app not found."
```

On the final line, I redirected `stderr` to `/dev/null` to silence it in the event that the application file didn't exist.  This is just an alternative method instead of checking first to confirm that the file *does* exist before choosing to delete it.

Comment: I'm getting an syntax error when trying this out.

19:21: syntax error: Expected expression but found end of line. (-2741)
: command not foundktop/Teams.sh: line 7: 
: command not foundktop/Teams.sh: line 10: 
: arguments must be process or job IDs 14: kill: 
: command not foundktop/Teams.sh: line 15: 
 not found.ns/Cisco Spark.app

(I saved the file as Teams.sh)

Comment: The nature of this list of errors suggests that the problem comes, not from the script, but from how the script was written out before being saved as `Teams.sh`.  My hunch is that the error is in the `osascript` section, from which the other subsequent errors are a knock-on effect from that one original typo.  I would advise you to check your version of this script, looking closely at quotes to ensure they are `'` or `"` and not smart quotes; and to ensure nothing was unnecessarily escaped, which can sometimes happen if a text editor is too clever for its own good.

Comment: Also, run your script through [**Shell Check**](https://www.shellcheck.net).  When I run the above code through it, the first warning is a result of my paragraph indents, which only exist here for stylistic purposes; the second is telling me that `egrep` is deprecated, which I am not concerned about right now but you can make the alteration as you see fit; and the last warning is to advise that I double-quote `$pid` in my `kill` command, which I typically do, except in that instance I know that `$pid` will only ever contain digits and no other characters, so quoting isn't necessary.